# How to handle event action on the whole component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I can bind an action to a `table`'s row using `{{action "foo"}}`; However, I converted each row into a component becase I need to encausulate some states inside each row.

How can I handle the default click event for the entire component in Ember way?

I am sure I can do the event binding in `didInsertElement` hook, but I am not sure this is the correct way to do so, or anti-Ember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out in your component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  click() {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Documentation: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/handling-events/

Comment: This is the right solution, accept the answer in 2mins.